# Image upload from php to mysql, fields are empty in BLOBS after upload

Tags: php, mysql, upload, image

I have a small picture upload script which is a kind of multiple-image upload purposed one.

Here is the total "after submit". The problem is, after upload, all the fields of pictures comes empty. None of the pictures can't be seing in the sql. What could be the problem?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if(!$conn)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db("newone",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}

$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['picone']['tmp_name']));
$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pictwo']['tmp_name']));
$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['picthree']['tmp_name']));
$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['picfour']['tmp_name']));
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['picone']['tmp_name']); //to know about image type etc.
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['pictwo']['tmp_name']); 
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['picthree']['tmp_name']); 
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['picfour']['tmp_name']); 




$q =  "INSERT INTO pictures(picone, pictwo, picthree, picfour) Values('$picone','$pictwo','$picthree','$picfour')";


$r = mysql_query($q,$conn);
if($r)
{
    header("Location: main.php");
    echo "Information stored successfully";
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: Storing images in database is not a very good practice. Store the path of the image instead

Comment: Obligatory: Your queries are prone to sql injection and also I'm pretty sure I would be able to upload a shell. Sanitize and validate inputs or you _will_ get hacked

Comment: Well, I'm quite lost about the advices you give me, basically, I can add those sort of protective additionals into the script I have, however, I don't know where to and how to... Secondly, I don't know how to save images into a folder and call from there to database by it name. Do you have any idea about the tags that I need to search or any indication that you can describe me to add into the script?

Answer (score 0):

you should learn a little about php before you tackle this
head over to php.net and learn the basics first

Your basic syntax is completely incorrect.
For instance where does $picone come from ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here:

```
$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['picone']['tmp_name']));
$aphoto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pictwo']['tmp_name']));
```

From where you get these variables (`$picone`, `$pictwo`, `$picthree`, `$picfour`)?

```
$q =  "INSERT INTO pictures(picone, pictwo, picthree, pic four)
Values('$picone','$pictwo','$picthree','$picfour')";
```

Put on the first line of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Answer (score -1):

```
file_get_contents($_FILES['picone']['tmp_name'])
```

..looks quite dodgy to me.

You should rather copy it somewhere first.